# Audio record in php

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I want to add an option to audio record(Voice Record) in my project. is php or javascript allow me to do the same??

I search for many of the audio record demos but they are browser specific.

i want simple and easy audio record in my php project which support all browser
Please help and thanks

Comment: try http://p5js.org/examples/examples/Sound__Record_Save_Audio.php

Comment: https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/

Comment: Hello it is not working for me, it always show the error i.e. enable mic and click the mouse to begin recording... thank u for ur help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RecordRTC though php.
checkout this github link.

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP